# Rational parametric equation graphing

Tags: parametric

[image]

Sketch the parametric equation on the Cartesian plane

Comment: What question do you have about this problem?

Comment: how to sketch it

Comment: Pick some t values. Calculate the x and y values. Plot those $(x, y)$ coordinates and join the dots.